Unable to web scrape using selenium
This is the code I have created using selenium to scrape data from the webpage https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/. This code is used to get the coordinates of an element having Xpath //*[@id="btnviewdetails"] using selenium. I have applied all try and exception method to make sure that the code is working.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def get_element_center_coordinates(element):
    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    center_x = location['x'] + size['width'] / 2
    center_y = location['y'] + size['height'] / 2
    return center_x, center_y

# URL of the web page
url = "https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/"

# Initialize the WebDriver (Make sure to have the correct path to chromedriver)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Open the URL and maximize the window
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(url)

    # Allow the page to load completely
    WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//body'))  # Wait until the body is present
    )
    print("Page loaded successfully.")

    # Add more sleep to ensure everything is loaded (if necessary)
    time.sleep(5)

    # Print the current page source for debugging
    page_source = browser.page_source
    print("Current page source:\n", page_source)

    # Adjust the XPath to the element you want to find
    element_xpath = '//*[@id="btnviewdetails"] and text()="Trade Mark Application/Application Details"]'    # Locate the element
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath))
    )
    print("Element found.")

    # Get the center coordinates of the element
    center_x, center_y = get_element_center_coordinates(element)
    print(f"Element center coordinates: ({center_x}, {center_y})")

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred:", str(e))

finally:
    # Close the browser
    browser.quit()

I am facing this error:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58581/devtools/browser/e8045f57-8eb5-4e79-9f39-101ab408ec63
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Exception occurred: Message: 
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF63FD01F52+60322]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FC7CEC9]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FB37EBA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FB87676]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FB8773C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FBCE967]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FBAC25F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FBCBC80]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FBABFC3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FB79617]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FB7A211]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6400194AD+3301629]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6400636D3+3605283]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF640059450+3563680]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF63FDB4326+790390]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FC8750F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FC83404]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FC83592]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF63FC72F9F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFD634E7344+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFD636226B1+33]

I want to retrieve the x and y coordinates of the element using the location Xpath //*[@id="btnviewdetails"].

your xpath selector is wrong, the element you want does not have any text, also is the ultimate goal to find the center coordinates? if there is a bigger problem you should ask that instead

Yes basically I want the x and y coordinates of the element for which the Xpath is mentioned. But yes the x and y coordinated which I can access them using pyautogui library to carry out my further operations. What is wrong in this xpath selector and do let me know that as well

the correct selector should be //a[@id="btnviewdetails"]

It is still not working. Same error is coming again.

https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/
This is the link to the website and i want to find out the coordinates of the button Trade Mark Application/Registered Mark

are you trying to find the screen coordinates or the browser window coordinates? the former is kinda tricky

I want to find out those coordinates that can be later on used to access using pyautogui library. Whichever will work, it will be great

depends on what you're trying to do with pyautogui and why are you not doing it with selenium?

I will do it with selenium only. But to click the button at specific coordinate, i need to use pyautogui. For the same, I require the exact coordinates

you can click the button at a specific coordinate with selenium, check this

Please have a look at this question. This will explain you my query really well. This is the link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78630433/unable-to-click-an-element-and-scrape-web-using-xpath-and-id-selenium. Please help me out in resolving the query.
